# alternative for download.file in R

Tags: r

I need to use `append mode` in `download.file` . The link I am downloading data from is https and doesn't have a support http version.

Problem:

I am on a Centos Machine.

Only internal method supports append mode.

Internal method does not support https URL's.

Is there an alternative I can use?

Comment: Why do you need to use append mode?

Comment: I need to append data to existing file and then move it to HDFS. Updating existing files in HDFS isn't really a solution so have to do it with download.file only @cdrini